# The precedence of the input/output operators

Tags: c++

The operator precedence tables just show the **bitwise shift operators** `<<` and `>>`. These are the same as the output operators, right?

In fact, it just so happens that C++ overloads these same operators to mean input/output, right? This is more of a tradition than anything more strict, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, same operators, different purpose.

Comment: why not add this as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure the origin of using `<<` and `>>` as operators for output is to do with two things.

1. It looks sensible.
2. The operators `<<` and `>>` are not that commonly used in "regular code". So they are available. It would be a real pain if they used operator +, -, * or /, since you couldn't write `cout + "The result is : x + y + endl;` and get x + y as the output. It's much less common than you write `cout << "The result is : " << x << y << endl;` - in this case, you'd have to use parenthesis: `cout << "The result is : " << (x << y) << endl;`

The order of operator precedence is defined by the language, no matter how you use the operators - which is one reason you don't want to use operator overload to do "strange" things in general - because it's easy to get something you don't really expect...